# Export an object from Blender to LDraw

Tags: software, ldraw

I have modeled a custom part in Blender and I would like to get it into LDraw format for use in LDCad and LPub3D.

I don't know much about 3D formats, but Blender can export collada, alembic, fbx, gltf 2.0, wavefront, and x3d.

I don't need the part to properly use LDraw primitives for my purposes (and I imagine that kind of conversion isn't possible), but just to convert the mesh into the sort of tris and quads that ldraw can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I exported from blender to STL file and used http://marc.klein.free.fr/lego/stl2dat/stl2dat.html to convert to DAT. The final result worked well, and you can see the custom part used alongside regular ldraw parts in the build instructions here: https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-68128/seejay/glittering-viper-rainbow-bears-starfighter/#details

The ldraw model was built in LDCad and the instructions were built in LPub3d.

Comment: Thanks for the rebrickable link.  The pens look great in the instructions and renders.

Answer (score 2):

I think LDPartEditor can do what you want.

https://nilsschmidt1337.github.io/ldparteditor/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I somehow missed it at the time. I ended up not using that approach, but worth exploring. I'll answer the question with what I ended up doing.